# How to prevent file from access if any file failed to write to a required folder

Tags: vb.net, file, read-write

I have 3 xml file to be written to a folder for client. while writing the 2 files got written perfectly but 3rd file failed. what are the ways by which I can prevent the client to open any file or all the files got deleted or locked if anything failed?

Answer (score 0):

If your application has delete privileges on the system, keep a record of the filenames to the files you're writing. If a file fails for whatever reason, go through the list of file names and delete the files from the directory. A simple string list with a for loop should do it.

Comment: Can we use transaction in writing files? if anything file writing failed, I can rollback it. How can we use transactions?

Comment: .NET does have a library called Transactional File Manager, but I haven't used it for VB. It will do what you're looking for in C#, but not all .NET libraries play well with both languages.

Comment: Best alternative would be to create you're own transaction with a try/catch and a string list of the filenames.